# How can I use templates to generate static web pages?

Tags: html, templates

I want to add one HTML file into another.

For example: I have `header.html` and `footer.html` 
Now I am trying to create `aboutus.html` where I want to add these two HTML files
there is no dynamic code in these file except JavaScript.

How can I do this without using any scripting language except JavaScript and CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of web sites with no dynamic content but have common elements, I generate the final pages on my development machine using Perl's [Template Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/) and upload the resulting static HTML files to the server. Works beautifully.

For example:

#### header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>[% title %]</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site.css" type="text/css">
<meta name="description" content="[% description %]">
<meta name="keywords" content="[% keywords.join(',') %]">
</head>

<body>

<div id="banner">
    <p>Banner</p>
</div>
```

#### footer.html

```
<address>
Last update:
[%- USE date -%]
[%- date.format(date.now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') -%]
</address>
</body>
</html>
```

#### aboutus.html

```
[%- INCLUDE header.tt.html
title       = 'About Us'
description = 'What we do, how we do it etc.'
keywords    = 'rock, paper, scissors'
-%]

<h1>About us</h1>

<p>We are nice people.</p>
```

You can now use [tpage](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template::Tools::tpage) or [ttree](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template::Tools::ttree) to build your pages.

Answer (score 6):

[Server Side Includes (SSI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) exist for this particular functionality. However, you need to have the server configured for such includes. Apache supports it. Not sure about other web servers.

Answer (score 4):

or [Server Side Includes (SSI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes), all embedding is done there on the server side...

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this *on the client side* without javascript is to use frames or iframes. If you want to use javascript, you can use AJAX. Most javascript frameworks provide corresponding convenience methods (e.g. jQuery's [`load`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) function).

Obviously there are many server side solutions, including the popular SSI extension for apache (see other posts).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you want but an entirely client side method of doing it would be to embed them with the `<object>` tag.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>About Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object data="header.html"><!--Something to display if the object tag fails to work. Possibly an iFrame--></object>
        <!--Content goes here...-->
        <object data="footer.html"></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

I do not think that this would work if either `header.html` or `footer.html` have javascript that accesses the parent document. Getting it to work the other way might be possible though.

Comment: What about browser support, or is that not an issue with this technique?

Comment: You can wrap an iframe inside of the <object> tag. If it works the iframe will be ignored. If the <object> tag is not supported it will be ignored so the iframe will be used.

Comment: PS. I think you could even nest a script tag inside the iframe tag in case frames are turn off or not supported.

Comment: PPS. If scripts are turned off too, or if a text based browser is being used then you are out of luck on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

Check out ppk's website (quirksmode.org), and go to the javascript archives,
(http://quirksmode.org/js/contents.html). He uses an ajax function he wrote called sendRequest (found at http://quirksmode.org/quirksmode.js). Since IE9+ plays nice with standards, I've simplified it some:

```
function sendRequest(url,callback,postData) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (!req) return;
    var method = (postData) ? "POST" : "GET";
    req.open(method,url,true);
    req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
    if (postData)
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState != 4) return;
        if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
            //  alert('HTTP error ' + req.status);
            return;
        }
        callback(req);
    }
    if (req.readyState == 4) return;
    req.send(postData);
}
```

Then use the sendRequest function by wrapping the setFooter, setHeader functions and any other content functions around it.

Answer (score 1):

why not use php or any other side scripting language?

doing this with javascript will not all users allow to watch your page.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this can be done with JS in a number of ways (AJAX, iframe insertion) it would be a very bad idea not to do this within the mark-up directly or (much) better on the server side.

A page reliant on JS for it's composition will not be fully rendered on a significant proportion of user's browsers, and equally importantly will not be correctly interpreted by google et al, if they like it at all.

You *can* do it, but please, please, don't.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously header.html and footer.html are not html files -- with full fledged headers etc. If you have just html snippets and you want to include them so you can create different pages - like aboutus.html, terms.html, you have a couple of options:

1. Use a framework like Rails - which allows you to use layouts and partials. [** heavy **]
2. Write a simple tool that will generate all the files by concat-ing the appropriate files.

I assume you are doing this to avoid duplicating header and footer content.

Comment: yes , i want avoid duplication and i want to manage it in a proper way

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using ajax to include the remote html files.

Comment: This would break the page for users with JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Framesets would be the way to do this without any script or serverside influences.

```
<frameset rows="100,*,100">
    <frame name="header" src="header.html" />
        <frame name="content" src="content.html" />
    <frame name="footer" src="footer.html" />
</frameset>
```

HTML5 framesets:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/html5_frameset.asp

This is a very dated solution, most web hosts will support server side includes or you could use php to include your files

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Cheers